# Extracting Linear Trend from Time Series Data

Tags: time-series, regression, linear-regression

I'd want to show that the behavior of our customers with the most customer support follows a different trend than our overall customers (with less support). As you can imagine, a linear fit to Time Series data with seasonality is going to lead to pretty bad r and p values. Therefore, my plan is to substract the linear fit from the datapoints and pick a few frequencies from a fourier transform.

My question is, can I argue, that the linear trend on its own is reasonable, when I show that the combination of the trend + fourier transform gets a decent fit (can I take the metrics of the combined fit?)? My goal would be to compare the trendlines of both customer groups (eventhough they are going to be pretty similar) to show our management that the support team is doing a great job.